# How can I show the program running time (time) in the X-axis of the graph?

Tags: qt

I have a dynamic graph in which i want to show Time in the X-Axis and some values in the Y-Axis, like an oscilloscope. I use QtChart to draw this plot. I am wondering how I can show the time of data acquisition in the X-Axis. The Format in which I want to show is mm:ss. My codes are as follows:

```
   //draw the line chart, dynamic update
   void MainWindow::drawLine()
   {

   //change the range of x-axis when added new point
   QDateTime bjtime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();

   //Sets the minimum range of the X-axis
   chart->axisX()->setMin(QDateTime::currentDateTime().addSecs(-60 * 1));

   //Sets the maximum range of the X-axis
   chart->axisX()->setMax(QDateTime::currentDateTime().addSecs(0));

   //When the earliest point on the curve is beyond the X-axis, remove the 
   //earliest point.
   if(series_CH1->count() > 1000)
   {
        series_CH1->removePoints(0,series_CH1->count() - 1000);
   }

   //Generate random Numbers as test data
   int Y1 = qrand()%9;

   //Add a new point to the end of the curve
   series_CH1->append(bjtime.toMSecsSinceEpoch(),Y1);
  }
```

when I run my program, the x-axis is :
month-day-year hour:minute, like 16-04-2019 19:53

what I want is minutes:seconds, and the time (x-axis) begins from 00:00 as I begin data aquisition rather than the current time.
Please help me how should I show the Time on my X Axis of the Graph.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a format for `QDateTimeAxis`. So you should set it to:

```
chart->axisX()->setFormat("mm:ss");
```

Also if you want it to start from `00:00`, the min range of x-axis could be start of epoch time and the max could be your desired max duration:

```
chart->axisX()->setMin(QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(0));

chart->axisX()->setMin(QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(3600*1000)); // one hour
```

And when appending new values you should calculate milliseconds for example using a `QElapsedTimer` or by differentiating current milliseconds since epoch from the value in start of running your app.